# Snake with orange spots found in South Florida

Tags: species-identification, snake

I found this snake near my doorstep. What species is it?

[image]

Comment: Although there's an answer with what looks like a very plausible ID, it would probably be helpful to give more information, such as the approximate size of the snake, what it was doing when you found it and so no.

Comment: [corn snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corn_snake).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks very much like a [red rat snake](http://myfwc.com/wildlifehabitats/imperiled/profiles/reptiles/red-rat-snake/) (*Pantherophis guttatus*). Nonvenomous, and wonderful.

[image]

Comment: First I thought that the coloration was off, but an image search showed a big variation and some of them looked exactly like the picture in the question.